# pyspark vs python vs numpy understanding?

Tags: python, numpy, apache-spark, pyspark

I am having trouble understanding the relationship between pyspark, spark, and python. I have tried to read up something on operating systems but still kind of confused.

So what I have searched are:

1. Pyspark is the python shell of spark.
2. Spark is a computing engine, possibly taking charge or distributing files to nodes, collect them and return them?
3. A shell is a program that interprets commands and translate into executable codes, by searching in the /bin directory.

But when I am writing the program, I am confused:

4. In Pyspark we can import Numpy and create Numpy objects. Then, does
   Spark also support Numpy projects?
5. We can write "from pyspark import SparkContext", then is pyspark a library just as numpy?
6. Where is the RDD objects in spark stored? I might be lacking some knowledge here, but what exactly is a Python object / numpy object / spark object? Are they stored somewhere on physical memory? Are they in the file system? How can there be objects from different programming libraries operate together in a python environment?

I feel I might be messing around with levels of abstractions here so any guidance will help! Thanks.

Comment: Numpy is a module and not a project.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Very* briefly (your question is way too broad, and this is actually not the best place for such inquiries):

1. pyspark is the Python *API* of Spark, and not just a shell (although it does include a shell); programs written in pyspark can be [submitted to a Spark cluster](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html) and run in a distributed manner.
2. More or less correct...
3. Also correct, roughly speaking (though irrelevant).
4. Numpy objects can be used with *py*spark, and they are indeed rather heavily used where needed - say, the linear algebra & machine learning libraries of *py*spark. Of course, they are of no use in the other Spark APIs (Scala/Java/R).
5. I'm not quite sure about the formal definition of a (Python) library, but yes, pyspark can be thought of as a library, too (or maybe as a set of libraries, since there are more subpackages in pyspark like Spark SQL & Spark ML); very recently it has also become available via [PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyspark/2.2.0) (i.e. it can be installed via `pip`).
6. ... well, here you become *really* broad... Let me just say that a big part in what goes on under the hood is due to [Py4j](https://www.py4j.org/), the unsung hero behind pyspark...